# Best way to edit yaml configuration settings in an erb form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a yaml file of application settings (arrays and hashes) that I would like a user to be able to edit through a view. What is the best way to do this?

Load the yaml file into an object that the view helper `fields_for` can use? So an ActiveModel or OpenStruct object?

These are application settings and are not associated with a particular user.

In the end I used an interim active record object with a serialze column as advised by Dmitri and then can use YAML.dump(app_config.settings, file) to create a yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to store users' settings in YAML files ? Wouldn't it be easier to create a column in the user's table, and add a serialization rule for that column - it would produce pretty much the same result, and you would be able to use all the stuff you need without any pain

If you are that stubborn, then create a separate action for user's controller and post a `form_tag` (i.e model-less behavor) form and then apply all the logic to re-write the data in the file, e.g .. YAML.load_file, update and write-back to file.

Comment: Ok I suppose I can not be so stubborn. If I create a table app_config with a column serialize: settings (rails 3.2), I just pass the app_config.settings value to my view and then use form tags with that yes?

Comment: I have a multi client app with a separate app instance and db for each client. Curreny i can drop and recreate a client db without losing configuration, which proves handy. Maybe a separate step to save the serialized attribute to yaml backup could work here?